counting same values across multiple columns within a row
I have a dataframe with columns for each day of the month.  For each day I have different values in the column.
Ex
 Emp Number 01-Jul 02-Jul 03-Jul 04-Jul 05-Jul 06-Jul 07-Jul 08-Jul 09-Jul
   0     C1    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
   1     C2    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
   2     C3    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
   3     C4    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
   4     C5    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH

I want output as
C1  WFH 7, WOH 2,
C2  WFH 7, WOH 2
C3  WFH 6, WOH 3
C4  WFH 6, WOH 3
C5  WFH 5, WOH 4

How do I iterate through these columns and get that count and what data type do I capture the output in.
I tried to use value counts and tried to capture it in Series datatype.  It did not work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please show what you tried. It helps us understand what you already know.

Are you importing these values from a CSV file or anything else?

You can use .melt() and .groupby() with .size() to achieve this. It is more straightforward and utilizes pandas functionalities effectively for reshaping and counting data.
Code:
# Reshape the DataFrame
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars=["Emp", "Number"], var_name="Date", value_name="Status")

# Group by 'Emp', 'Number' and 'Status', then count
result = df_melted.groupby(['Emp', 'Number', 'Status']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

Output:

for emp_number, row in result.iterrows():
    status_counts = ', '.join(f'{status} {count}' for status, count in row.items())
    print(f'{emp_number}  {status_counts}')


>     C1  WFH 7, WOH 2
>     C2  WFH 7, WOH 2
>     C3  WFH 6, WOH 3
>     C4  WFH 6, WOH 3
>     C5  WFH 5, WOH 4


Since DataFrames are columnar oriented, you'll need to reshape the data to retrieve the correct value counts for each row.
Additionally your expected output looks more like a report rather than a specific DataFrame so we'll break this question into 2 parts:

value_counts across each row
displaying a report of these counts

from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO('''
Emp Number 01-Jul 02-Jul 03-Jul 04-Jul 05-Jul 06-Jul 07-Jul 08-Jul 09-Jul
0       C1    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
1       C2    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
2       C3    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
3       C4    WFH    WFH    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
4       C5    WFH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WOH    WOH    WFH    WFH
''')

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(buffer, sep=r'\s+')

# ① Aggregate data
counts = (
    df.set_index(['Emp', 'Number'])
    .T
    .apply(lambda s: s.value_counts())
    .T
)

print(counts)
#             WFH  WOH
# Emp Number
# 0   C1        7    2
# 1   C2        7    2
# 2   C3        6    3
# 3   C4        6    3
# 4   C5        5    4

# ② Generate report
for row in counts.itertuples():
    print(f'{row.Index[1]}  WFH {row.WFH}, WOH {row.WOH}')
# C1  WFH 7, WOH 2
# C2  WFH 7, WOH 2
# C3  WFH 6, WOH 3
# C4  WFH 6, WOH 3
# C5  WFH 5, WOH 4


This is excellent and spot on.  Thanks a lot Cameron Riddell.  Greatly appreciate it.

Great! If this solution works for you, would you mind upvoting and selecting it as the correct answer? That way if anyone else has a similar question they can quickly find a working solution. Happy coding :)

Another way using agg. I think this should be faster than apply
out = df.set_index(["Emp", "Number"]).agg(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).reset_index()
print(out)

   Emp Number  WFH  WOH
0    0     C1    7    2
1    1     C2    7    2
2    2     C3    6    3
3    3     C4    6    3
4    4     C5    5    4


Wow... all great answers... thanks.  My end goal is not the report, but using that output for further calculations.  But all these different methods, I guess all of them will work for me.  Thanks guys.

@Rama its not about what is working, its also about what is working better
